# Getting all rows with common value in column A and specific value in column B

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL I have table *matcher_table* with columns *matcher* and *type*. Records which are put here can have many different values for *type* column. One type matches another one only when value for *matcher* column is the same.
Let's say I have to find all *matching* records for 5 *types*. Which would be the best approach/query in order to achieve this?

---

The table would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `matcher_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `matcher` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Now let's say we have this values in the table:

```
id | matcher | type
1  | match1  | type1
2  | match1  | type2
3  | match1  | type3
4  | match2  | type4
5  | match2  | type2
6  | match3  | type1
7  | match3  | type2
8  | match3  | type3
```

If I need to get matching data for types (type1, type2, type3), than I must get rows with ID 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8 (due to match1 and match3).
If I need to get matching data for types (type1, type2, type3, type4) than I must get no records fulfilling this match.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.)

Comment: have you tried self join?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ not sure if this works for my scenario. I need each matching record in a different row.

Comment: @jarlh Did it. Sorry for being late, but I was forced to leave the computer for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend three `exists` clauses -- because you want the original rows:

```
select mt.*
from matcher_table mt
where exists (select 1
              from matcher_table mt2
              where mt2.matcher = mt.matcher and mt2.type = 'type1'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from matcher_table mt2
              where mt2.matcher = mt.matcher and mt2.type = 'type2'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from matcher_table mt2
              where mt2.matcher = mt.matcher and mt2.type = 'type3'
             );
```

The advantage of this approach is that it avoids aggregation and it can make use of an index on `matcher_table(matcher, type)`.  I would expect this to have very good performance in comparison to other approaches.

Comment: The fastest one is by far the solution contained in accepted answer.

Comment: @artaxerxe . . . I'm not surprised that this is faster, which is why I suggested it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below query -

```
select *
from `matcher_table`
where matcher in (select matcher
                  from `matcher_table`
                  where type in ('type1', 'type2', 'type3')
                  group by matcher
                  having count(distinct type) = 3)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c582e65b020febb57cd1f4ea1c6f5275) is the demo.

Answer (score 1):

You could join to a sub-query that groups on the matcher field.
And which only returns those with all the wanted types.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM matcher_table t
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT matcher
   FROM matcher_table
   WHERE `type` IN ('type1', 'type2', 'type3')
   GROUP BY matcher
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `type`) = 3
) q ON q.matcher = t.matcher;
```