# Selecting only those rows which match all the values specified under IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CAR (model, color, engine) #PrimaryKey(model,engine)

(1081, 'blue', 'ec41')
(1082, 'cyan', 'ec41')
(1083, 'rose', 'ec41')

(1081, 'green', 'dc41')
(1082, 'white', 'dc41')
```

For this set of model(1081,1082,1083) output should contain color -(blue, cyan,rose) while colors green and white should be left out.(Because a member(1083) is absent in engine(dc41).
I tried with this:

```
select color from car where model in (1081,1082,1083)
```

But, above outputs green and white as well. How do I restrict it like - Return color from only those engines which have all the models supplied.

Comment: Specify the expected result set as well.

Comment: he did ? @jarlh well more or less, seams he only wants `(blue, cyan,rose)` when looking at the SQL and the information a little bit above it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all rows with common value in column A and specific value in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798024/getting-all-rows-with-common-value-in-column-a-and-specific-value-in-column-b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a sub-query that returns engines having all 3 models (1081,1082,1083).

```
select color
from car
where engine in (
    select engine
    from car
    where model in (1081,1082,1083)
    group by engine
    having count(distinct model) = 3)
```

Comment: never mind mine other comment readed the column and data wrong need more coffee ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, it took me some coffee to dechipher the problem.

Comment: I need coffee to understand the solution, I'll be back soon.
Thanks, Sirs.

Comment: Above solution works perfectly with the table structure defined above. If allowed, I'd like to add this row to the table `(1084, 'orange', 'ec41')` , now the output should not contain this newly added row. I am really sorry, I missed this row.

Comment: I'll try first and then post for confirming the correctness of the solution.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, jarlh: This newly added row has turned the tables on me :) , I guess I need to study more.

Comment: *"now the output should not contain this newly added row. I am really sorry, I missed this row."* *"This newly added row has turned the tables on me"*  @Mr.President .. .Uhm `model 1084` cant be selected with this query so not sure what you are doing....

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I am able to do it, but not sure about the solution as it contains 2 `in` for `model`. Shall I post a new question with improper solution? Will you take a look at it?

Comment: *"Shall I post a new question with improper solution? "* That would be usefull, be sure to mention this post in your question else otherwise you risk it might be easy closevoted for question duplication.. *"Will you take a look at it? "*  No idea, pretty sure somebody else also can help you out

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much, would do as you suggested.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, jarlh - I have posted a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837129/returning-only-those-rows-which-match-all-the-values-specified-under-in-clause If you have time, please look at it.