# Returning only those rows which match all the values specified under IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have asked a question here - [Selecting only those rows which match all the values specified under IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834312/selecting-only-those-rows-which-match-all-the-values-specified-under-in-clause)
But, I missed certain details, and hence asking again with proper table information.

My table goes like this:

```
create table cars(
  model int,
  color varchar(10),
  fuel varchar(10),
  engine varchar(10),
  primary key (model, engine)
);

insert into cars values
(1081, 'blue', 'petrol', 'ec41'),
(1082, 'cyan', 'diesel', 'ec41'),
(1083, 'gray', 'diesel', 'ec41'),
(1084, 'gold', 'petrol', 'ec41'),

(1081, 'green', 'petrol', 'dc41'),
(1082, 'white', 'diesel', 'dc41');
```

With this set as input for `in` clause - model(1081, 1082, 1083), I want the output to be:

```
(1081, 'blue', 'petrol', 'ec41')
(1082, 'cyan', 'diesel', 'ec41')
(1083, 'gray', 'diesel', 'ec41')
```

Here, row `(1084, 'gold', 'petrol', 'ec41')` has been left out.
Also, no row has been selected from engine 'dc41' as it doesn't have all of  the supplied models (1083 is missing).

With help, from the answer to my previous question, I came up with this improper kind of query:

```
select *
from car
where model in (1081,1082,1083)
and engine in (
       select engine
       from car where model in (1081,1082,1083)
       group by engine
       having count(distinct model) = 3
)
```

No. of values supplied to in clause is variable.It could be 3 or 4 or 5.
I had to put an outer select as aggregate function doesn't allow other columns to be selected.

How could I do it properly?Many thanks.

Comment: why do you think your query is "improper"?

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for replying. It is twice searching for models, once it does it on all the `engines` then after filtering them, it searches again in a particular `engine`. For a large table, I think it should look only once, this is why I think it's improper.

Comment: I think you are hinting me to write inefficient instead of improper!

Comment: Sometimes these things are just necessary, because of the way SQL works. Although someone may come up with a more elegant solution, still. But...are you experiencing any kind of definable performance issue with this, when you run it on a large dataset? Have you checked the [EXPLAIN plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) for your query to see what processing it will actually do? The database engine takes your written SQL and optimises it as much as it can before actually executing it...you may find it doesn't do exactly as the literal SQL would suggest it might.

Comment: @ADyson is correct, based on your criteria, you need a pre-qualifier on the distinct engines qualifying models which returns just the engine.  Then you explicitly need to qualify again for all rows of that engine AND the same models... Sometimes it is, what it is.

Comment: SQL does not have a built-in relational division operator so you'll have to use this.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all, I'll use this and may be try to improve it. Explain is really nice. Looking at division @SalmanA

Comment: *"SQL does not have a built-in relational division operator so you'll have to use this"* @SalmanA  How often i wished SQL or some SQL dialect i was working with had a `DIVIDE/DIVISION [BY]` syntax to be used like `UNION` to do relational division defined in the [relational  algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7))  as that would make things so much more easy... Still not totally understanding why it was never added to the SQL standard...

Comment: *"The database engine takes your written SQL and optimises it as much as it can before actually executing it...you may find it doesn't do exactly as the literal SQL would suggest it might. "* @ADyson you meant executing .. `EXPLAIN <query>; SHOW WARNINGS;`? right? Then indeed in some MySQL versions you can see which rewrite was happing still it might not be valid SQL in there..